# Cannot resolve variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to write a batch file which will be searching, depends on what version on windows is user working, SIP folder and delete it.

Already i have something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0

cls

echo -------------------------------
choice /c yn /t 1 /d n /M "Automode will start in 5 sec..."

if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "2" goto auto_no
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" goto auto_yes



::========== MANUAL ============================================================
::========== CHOICE ============================================================
:auto_no
cls

echo -------------------------------
echo Starting Manual Mode...


:: ver | findstr /i "5\.1\." > nul
:: IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto auto_no_winxp

ver | findstr /i "10\.0\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto auto_no_winxp

ver | findstr /i "6\.0\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto auto_no_winvista
ver | findstr /i "6\.1\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto auto_no_win7
ver | findstr /i "6\.3\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto auto_no_win81
:: ver | findstr /i "10\.0\." > nul
:: IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto auto_no_Win10


:auto_no_winxp
echo WINDOWS XP Detected..
echo Switching to direct choose..
GOTO auto_no_direct

:auto_no_winvista
echo WINDOWS Vista Detected..
echo WINDOWS 10 Detected..
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Type" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Domain" /C:"Logon Server"

GOTO end

:auto_no_win7
echo WINDOWS 7 Detected..
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Type" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Domain" /C:"Logon Server"

GOTO end

:auto_no_win81
echo WINDOWS 8.1 Detected..
echo WINDOWS 10 Detected..
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Type" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Domain" /C:"Logon Server"

GOTO end

:auto_no_win10
echo WINDOWS 10 Detected..
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Type" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Domain" /C:"Logon Server"

GOTO end

:auto_no_direct
set source="%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\"
IF EXIST "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\" (
echo Ms Lync Communicator directory found..
echo ^-^> MS Lync 2010
echo Profiles:


for %%x in (*.txt) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x] !choice[%%x]!
)


set /p select=Type profile then press ENTER:
echo Pointer_procent: %select%
echo Pointer_wykrzyk: !select!

echo Selected: !choice[%select%]!






) ELSE (
echo There not found Communicator directory
echo ^-^> No MS Lync installed..
echo ^-^> Terminating..Press any key
)

GOTO end



GOTO end
::========== MANUAL ============================================================


::========== AUTO ==============================================================
::========== CHOICE ============================================================
:auto_yes
cls
echo Consipz - Lync Profile Reset
echo -------------------------------
echo Starting Auto Mode...
GOTO end
::========== AUTO ==============================================================


:end
pause > nul
```

and i have a problem in this section:

```
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x] !choice[%%x]!
)


set /p select=Type profile then press ENTER:
echo Pointer_procent: %select%
echo Pointer_wykrzyk: !select!

echo Selected: !choice[%select%]!
```

Im trying to ask user for selected option.
But i cannot to show which is he selecting. For example:
User after seeing options like:

```
1] choice1.txt
2] choice2.txt
```

and select..maybe 2
should to see:

```
Selected: choice2.txt
```

I was trying almost everything and i know there is probably a problem with SETLOCAL.

Please help ;)
PS: Skip code when trying to resolve what kind of Windows does the user use.
I switched the labels target on purpose couse im using W10

***EDIT:***
It was helpfull :)
I resolved my problem with solution like:

```
if *condition* (
goto yes
)else(
goto no
)
:yes
REM menu as files

:no
REM terminate
```

Now i am standing in front of another problem. How can I make there would be not *.txt files as an options but folders. Name of those folders is started by "sip", like sip_john@doe.com?

When  i'm trying to this code:

```
for %%x in ('dir /b /s /a:d "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\*"') do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
```

i see something like this as a result:

```
Profiles:
1] 'dir
2] /b
3] /s
4] /a:d
Type profile then press ENTER:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the indicated code is placed inside an `if`. So you will need delayed expansion for the `!select!` variable and delayed expansion for the `!choice[...]!` *array*. As something like `!choice[!select!]!` can not be properly parsed, a trick is needed

```
for %%r in (!select!) do echo !choice[%%r]!
```

Storing the value of the index variable in a `for` replaceable parameter we can get the two delayed variables without the syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach (`call` a subroutine):

```
:auto_no_direct
set source="%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\"
IF EXIST "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\" (
  echo Ms Lync Communicator directory found..
  echo ^-^> MS Lync 2010
  echo Profiles:


  for %%x in (*.txt) do (
    set /a count=count+1
    set choice[!count!]=%%x
  )
  for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
     echo %%x] !choice[%%x]!
  )

  set /p select=Type profile then press ENTER:
  echo Pointer_procent: %select%
  echo Pointer_wykrzyk: !select!

  call :subSelect "choice[!select!]"
  echo Selected: choice[!select!] !Selected!

) ELSE (
  echo There not found Communicator directory
  echo ^-^> No MS Lync installed..
  echo ^-^> Terminating..Press any key
)

GOTO end

:subSelect
set "Selected=!%~1!"
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

And on all end i tryied this code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /on /b /a:d /p "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\*"') do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
```

Thanks fpr YOUR HELP!